# Upon opening a new instance of a form, a file that should be read, is not

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, instance, save

In my application, I have one form. When a button is pressed to open a new instance of that form I have the following code (Which also is run at first application start up):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Vlad\Documents\" + this.Text.ToString() +"_Settings_Save.rtf"))
            {
                try
                {
                    richTextBox2.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\Vlad\Documents\" + this.Text.ToString() + "_Settings_Save.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
                    richTextBox1.LoadFile(richTextBox2.Text + @"\" + this.Text.ToString() + "_Save_File.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);                       
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
            else if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Vlad\Documents\" + this.Text.ToString() + "_Settings.txt"))
            {
                richTextBox2.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\Vlad\Documents\" + this.Text.ToString() + "_Settings.txt");
                richTextBox1.LoadFile(richTextBox2.Text + @"\" + this.Text.ToString() + "_TestSave.txt");
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            double n = Application.OpenForms.Count;
            double x = n + 1;
            Form1 newForm = new Form1();
            newForm.Show();
            newForm.Text = "Notables " + x.ToString();

        }
```

I was hoping that when a new instance is opened, the new form would do the form1_load event and load that file.

This application is meant to be universal in saving. Meaning, you can open and close as many instances as you want, and in EACH instance, there will be the same text as before the instance was closed.

I apologize if this was confusing.

Its time for me to go now, I will respond to all questions tomorrow morning. About 6 hours from now.

Thank you.

--EDIT--
Here is the extreme simplification of what I wanted to do.

If the user opens two instances of form 1. and then closes them. Upon opening each, both of the forms should have saved data from the last close

--EDIT 2--
Now, Here is a simplification of what is happening instead.

The application does indeed save correctly but however, new instances do not open the correct files. They simply open the same file as from the first instance. but the save file is correct.

Comment: What is in this.Text.ToString(); ? Does the resulting path actually exist? I can imagine this.Text is empty. What happens if you put in a MessageBox in the last else? Also; which version of c# are you using? Now you have tagged them all. That can't be right.

Comment: Given that `this.Text` is already a string, there's no need to call `.ToString()` on it.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis "this.Text" is the form's header field/the text of the form. I am Using CS Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your code under a debugger, and step through it to see what it is doing.

I suspect the problem is that you open the form *before* you set the Text property to the name of the file you want to be loaded, so the Load() method generates invalid filenames and thus executes the empty `else {}` block.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I had answered my question at the exact same time as you did. :D Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the file exists.  It's probably not getting loaded because of some exception, and you can't see that because you have an empty catch block:

```
try 
{ 
    richTextBox2.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\Vlad\Documents\" + this.Text.ToString() + "_Settings_Save.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText); 
    richTextBox1.LoadFile(richTextBox2.Text + @"\" + this.Text.ToString() + "_Save_File.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);                        
} 
catch 
{ 

}
```

Catch the exception and notify the user, instead:

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
    NotifyUser(exception);
}
```

Notify user could raise a message box, or write to a log file, or both.

Also, if the file doesn't exist, you could raise an exception or call NotifyUser to alert the user (i.e., at this point, you the developer) of that fact:

```
else
{
    NotifyUser("File not found: " + fileName);
}
```

Comment: When I use:
catch (Exception e)
{
    NotifyUser(e);
}

The name of NotifyUser does not exist in the current context.
A Local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a parent or current scope to denote something else.

But I do in fact understand what you mean about the raising a flag which tells me when something IS wrong.

Comment: @Vlad781 NotifyUser is basically a placeholder implying that you would also write a new method to do whatever notification you think is best.  The "name does not exist" error happens because you haven't yet written that method.  The 'e' thing is because we already have the parameter `EventArgs e` -- a good example of why we should avoid single-letter identifiers.  I've edited the answer to fix that one.

Comment: Ok, so I have changed to:
catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fail", "Fail 01");
                }

However, no message boxes were shown on the new instance of the form.

Comment: OK, I found my problem, but props to you for teaching me to correctly use the try-catch exception. I would vote you up, but I don't have the Rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Form1 newForm = new Form1();
        newForm.Show();
        newForm.Text = "Notables " + x.ToString();
```

when you are calling a new instance, simply call another method to do that work for you. If you need to save some data from the first instance, save it in an application wide object or in a static variable.

Comment: No. If the user opens two instances of form 1. and then closes them. Upon opening each, both of the forms should have saved data from the last close.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that the form was being opened as form 1 then changing to a specific text. and in between those two processes the rest of my application was not able to run the first part of my code. I fixed this by switching the Form.Show() AFTER I change its text programmatically.

```
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            double n = Application.OpenForms.Count;
            double x = n + 1;
            Form1 newForm = new Form1();
            newForm.Text = "Notables " + x.ToString();
            newForm.Show();
        }
```